# Migrating Magento 1 db to Magento 2, Database is on Amazon RDS and the other is local to the new server

Tags: mysql, migration, amazon-rds, rds, magento

The company handling the migration is using a tool called UB Data Migration tool to migrate the magento website from 1.x which has its database hosted on Amazon RDS to a new amazon instance that contains the Database locally on the server (MYSQL).
The issue is that they are receiving Gateway Timeout, I have checked the Amazon RDS VPC and Security Groups and remote access to the DB is granted. on the other server I tried changing the timeout of php fpm and httpd to no avail.

The company working on the migration are asking me to make the IP Address Shareable! HOW! its on RDS not on the server for me to make the ip shareable. or am i missing something here?

any help is most appreciated.

Comment: Will the new instance be hosted by Amazon?  If so, should Amazon be making the IP Address Shareable?

Answer (score 0):

The timeout is probably cause because you're missing "Inbound rule" port for RDS database in your vpc. So when you try to connect manually from the new EC2 to your RDS DB, what happends, timeout?

Check your configuration and compare it with the details in [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_VPC.Scenarios.html)